# Why is duplicated() showing different results on similar codes, of the same dataframe?

Tags: python

I am currently working on an NLP project on my own, and am having some troubles even after reading through the documentations. scraped reddit posts and wanted to find out which posts are duplicated for the 'selftext' and 'title' column. The 3 codes shown below are what was inputted and the results are shown in the picture

May i ask why is there non duplicated posts for code 2 and 3 with reference to code 1?

(1)`investing_data[['selftext','title']][investing_data.duplicated(subset=['selftext','title'])]`

(2)`investing_data[['selftext', 'title']][investing_data.duplicated(subset=['selftext'])]`

(3)`investing_data[['selftext', 'title']][investing_data.duplicated(subset=['title'])]`

[screenshot of the 3 codes above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcuTb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have in fact different data that you check for duplicates:

What you see in all three lines are the duplicates, i.e. the second, third and so forth occurrence of the line.

- In line (1): you check if both `selftext` and `title` are the same.
- In line (2): you check for entries that have a duplicated `selftext`.
- In line (3): you check for entries that have a duplicated `title`.

Using your visualisation you only see the duplicates, but not all entries that actually are duplicates (i.e. including the first occurrence).

For that you can use something like the following:

```
investing_data[investing_data['selftext'] == investing_data[investing_data.duplicated(subset=['selftext'])]['selftext']][['selftext', 'title']]
```

What is done with this is that you get all duplicates that contain `selftext` and and search in the original dataframe for exactly those entries and display `selftext` and `title`.

Comment: Thank you! for line(2) and line(3), it show show all of the duplicated texts within their respective columns from what i gather. However, for line(2) and line(3), why am i not seeing duplicated selftext? 

Eg; in line(2) for row 428 and 580, under selftext, there is no other repetition of selftext, may I further enquire why is that so? (I am especially confused by this)

Comment: I think you do have duplicated `selftext` values in those columns, they are just out of order. When you add `.sort_values(by="selftext")` to my previous code you should see it ;)

Comment: You are welcome! If my answers helped you you can accept them so that others can find it as well :)

Comment: I have answered, apologies, new to stackoverflow!
Once again, thank you for your replies and guidance again!